# How do i see one column with two different condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, pivot

I have columns in one! table; example  (Hallo(Deutsch)=Hello, Montag(Deutsch)=Monday)

```
Id, LanguageID, ResourceName, ResourceValue  
1   1           Hello         Hello  
2   2           Hello         Hallo  
3   1           Monday        Monday  
4   2           Monday        Montag
```

How can I see to results of a query like this:

```
ResourceName   ResourceValue(languageID=1) ResourceValue(LanguageID=2)  
Hello          Hello         Hallo  
Monday         Monday        Montag
```

Comment: Please add some clarification to your question and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried) already, can you show us some SQL code?

Comment: ... it was formatted better before your edit. And before your table had 4 columns... now it has 3.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the result using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select ResourceName,
  max(case when languageid = 1 then ResourceValue end) Language1,
  max(case when languageid = 2 then ResourceValue end) Language2
from yourtable
group by resourcename
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89894/1).

If you have additional `LanguageId` values, then you can add more case expressions.

Answer (score 2):

This might work...

```
select 
    t1.resourcename,
    t1.resourcevalue,
    t2.resourcevalue
from
    tablename t1,
    tablename t2
where
    t1.resourcename = t2.resourcename and
    t1.languageid = 1 and
    t2.languageid = 2
```

Comment: To be fair, Bluefeet's answer is probably better if your db supports the CASE statement (I know a few do, not sure which ones don't).

Comment: `CASE` is ANSI standard syntax so it should be supported by all database products.

Comment: @Bluefeet Thanks! I learn something every day. Yeah, mine works, but bluefeet's is better, pick his.